# how to cancel promises with bluebird

Tags: promise, bluebird, cancellation

I think I misunderstand how promise cancellation with bluebird works. I wrote a test that demonstrates this. How do I make it green? Thanks:

```
describe('cancellation tests', () => {
  function fakeFetch() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(1);
      }, 100);
    });
  }

  function awaitAndAddOne(p1) {
    return p1.then(res => res + 1);
  }

  it('`cancel` cancels promises higher up the chain', () => {
    const p1 = fakeFetch();
    const p2 = awaitAndAddOne(p1);

    expect(p2.isCancellable()).toBeTruthy();
    p2.cancel();

    return p2
      .then(() => {
        console.error('then');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        expect(p2.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); // Expected value to be truthy, instead received false
        expect(p1.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); 
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: How could `p1` be cancelled? It already is fulfilled in the line `p1 = Promise.resolve(1)`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing out, not having my best day today xD. I have updated the snippet, can you take a look again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Karen if correct. But the issue is that your test is also a bit wrong

If you look at the `isCancellable` method

```
Promise.prototype.isCancellable = function() {
    return this.isPending() && !this.isCancelled();
};
```

This is just checking if the `promise` is `pending` and is not already cancelled. This doesn't mean then cancellation is enabled.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html

If you see the above url, it quotes below

> The cancellation feature is **by default turned off**, you can enable it using Promise.config.

And if you look at the `cancel` method

```
Promise.prototype["break"] = Promise.prototype.cancel = function() {
    if (!debug.cancellation()) return this._warn("cancellation is disabled");
```

Now if I update your test correct like below

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var expect = require("expect");

describe('cancellation tests', () => {
    function fakeFetch() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(1);
        }, 100);
      });
    }

    function awaitAndAddOne(p1) {
      return p1.then(res => res + 1);
    }

    it('`cancel` cancels promises higher up the chain', () => {
      const p1 = fakeFetch();
      const p2 = awaitAndAddOne(p1);

      value = p2.isCancellable();
      expect(p2.isCancellable()).toBeTruthy();
      p2.cancel();

      expect(p2.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); // Expected value to be truthy, instead received false
      expect(p1.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); 
    });
  });
```

You can see that cancellation is not enable and it executes the warning code

[image: Cancellation is disabled]

The execution results fail as expected

```
spec.js:46
  cancellation tests
spec.js:46
    1) `cancel` cancels promises higher up the chain
spec.js:78
  0 passing (3m)
base.js:354
  1 failing
base.js:370
  1) cancellation tests
base.js:257
       `cancel` cancels promises higher up the chain:
     Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()
Expected value to be truthy, instead received
  false
      at Context.it (test/index.test.js:37:36)
```

Now if you update the code to enable cancellation

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var expect = require("expect");

Promise.config({
  cancellation: true
});

describe('cancellation tests', () => {
    function fakeFetch() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(1);
        }, 100);
      });
    }

    function awaitAndAddOne(p1) {
      return p1.then(res => res + 1);
    }

    it('`cancel` cancels promises higher up the chain', () => {
      const p1 = fakeFetch();
      const p2 = awaitAndAddOne(p1);

      value = p2.isCancellable();
      expect(p2.isCancellable()).toBeTruthy();
      p2.cancel();

      expect(p2.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); // Expected value to be truthy, instead received false
      expect(p1.isCancelled()).toBeTruthy(); 
    });
  });
```

It works!

[image: Cancellation works]

Comment: thanks for an in-depth answer. I found out the underlying problem for me was using async / await which does not seem to play well with bluebird

Comment: more specifically -- if you change `awaitAndAddOne` to `async`, then p2._cancellationParent === p1is false. If you keep it without async, it will evaluate to true, and thanks to that the cancellation works.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html):

> The cancellation feature is by default turned off, you can enable it using Promise.config.

Seems like you didn't enable the `cancellation` flag on the Promise itself:

```
Promise.config({
  cancellation: true
});

describe(...
```

Comment: please note that it is turned on, as seen in `expect(p2.isCancellable()).toBeTruthy();`